# Boot error on MacBookPro ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, grub2, macbook-pro, grub-efi

I've zeroed my MacBookPro 13" (late-2012) and I've installed Ubuntu 21.04 (single OS on the machine).
The installation went well, but when rebooting, I keep getting stuck on the grub prompt.

I've booted on a live boot-repair, and tried to repair the boot (with Secure Boot disabled).

Boot-repair finishes perfectly fine, and tells me to reboot.

However,

1. It keep getting stuck on the grub prompt
2. The pastbin has some lines I don't understand.

Here is the PasteBin from the boot-repair actions : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CvnPrWz3Pw/

On line 33, I have this :

```
No /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/etc/grub.d/ folder.
```

And on line 68 :

```
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
```

The pop-up said to check that the device correclty boots on the `sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`, but it's the case, if I look at the output of the `efibootmgr` command.

Answer (score 0):

Just joined. Looks like there's a bug in the installer Ubuntu 21.04 failing to install `grub/efi` bootloader in macbook.

What I did is... after installing Ubuntu 21.04, I booted again from live USB, download `refind_0.12.0-1_amd64.deb` ([link here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/refind/download)) and install using `dpkg -i`, select yes when asked to "install". Then reboot.

I didn't mount any drive partition.

This solution works for me, since I'm also multibooting OS'es. Hope it helps.